# How do I create a header on only one page in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, list, bullets, page

I'm writing a multi-page resume and I have a long bulleted list that breaks in between page one and two. Since I have a lot of details about my time at one company I want to have the company's name followed by "(cont.)" as a header on page 2 but leave page 1 alone. That is to say, I don't want anything resembling a header on any page except page 2, so the top margin of page 1 should be unaffected. How do I do this?

Comment: What version of Word? A workaround could also be inserting a floating image or floating text box. But I do remember doing exactly this in a class for lower division in Business majors in computer science. Class totally sucked and had to do mundane exercises in all MS Suite stuff. I'm pretty sure it's there. Good luck!

Comment: Also you question is a little murky. I read it again and don't know what you want now. Just say headers are as follows:  page 1: Company Name, page 2: Company Name cont'd? Or do you mean you have a header on page1 only? Or are you saying that you want two headers?

Comment: I thought I was clear but I've clarified further. I want no header at all on page 1. I do not want two headers.

Comment: You can have the first header bkank. It still works.. it's an exsmple.

Comment: Sorry, my phone is hard to type. Back on the PC. First header in the screen shot is only an example. Putting text is only an option. You may leave the first page's header BLANK. This is an example for both scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

[image]

A picture is worth a thousand words:

- Double click on the header.
- Select Design Tab.
- Options Section →
  Check Box "Different First Page".

*First header is just an example. THIS CAN BE LEFT BLANK, of course.

> I want to have "Company name (cont.)" as a header on page 2 but leave
>   page 1 alone.

After exploring more about your comments, I'd suggest not using this as a header --

> "Company name (cont.)"

. In this case I would suggest, NOT to continue a Name onto a second page, but instead increase the bottom margin on the previous page to make room for completing the Company Name.

Comment: Okay, but let's say I had three pages. Wouldn't using "Different First Page" mean pages 2 and 3 would have the same header?

Comment: Yes. You would need to do something else to have a header on only 1 page. In that sense, it's no longer a "header."

Comment: @KyleDelaney --- it's a header. Different first page is all there is. A header is meant to be duplicated. I'd suggest that if you want to do each page different (it will no longer be a header then it would be just text), then uses a text box, then choose properties in that text box, select float over text, that way you can put it up in the margins where the Header would be. A Header is defined, what you want is not a header by the sounds of your description.

Comment: @KyleDelaney in other words, what user8356 said is true. It's no longer a "header".

Comment: Okay, so if you want to put a (cont.) at the top of the page without breaking the bulleted list, a text box is the standard way to do that?

Comment: I'd like to clarify that the company name isn't what's being continued. No company name is that long. It's the bulleted list that pertains to that company that's being continued.

Comment: That's correct. After all your comments it's not a header per say that you're looking for it's just customizing a page and that case if you want to put things in the above margin I would use a textbox select properties and hover above text and you should be good to go.